# Using chronometer in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, chronometer

as the title said i'm using the chronometer with Xamarin, but here is my problem : it's impossible to set the chronometer to 00:00. I tried the method to set the base to 0 but it didn't work.

Here is my code :

```
Chronometer chrono = FindViewById<Chronometer>(Resource.Id.chronometer1);

void startButton(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            chrono.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
            buttonStop.Enabled = true;
            chrono.Base = 0;
            chrono.Start();
        }
```

But when i start the chrono it starts from the SystemClock.elapsedRealtime().

Is anyone has an idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to start from `0`, assign it the current time so the *delta time* is `0`.

```
chrono.Base = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime();
```

> You can give it a start time in the elapsedRealtime() timebase, and it counts up from that, or if you don't give it a base time, it will use the time at which you call start().

re: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html